# prometheus using html content in alerts annotations and using it in email template

Tags: prometheus

So our alert looks like

```
ALERT alert_name
   condition
   FOR 30s
   LABELS {some labels}
   ANNOTATIONS {
       header = "<b> data is {{ $labels.label_name }} </b>"
   }
```

email template looks like.

```
{{ define "our_default_template" }}
{{range .Alerts}}
{{ .Annotations.header }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

alertmanager.yml looks like

```
receivers:
- name: 'email-sender'
  email_configs:
  - to: "email address"
    send_resolved: true
    html: '{{ template "our_default_template" . }}'

templates:
- '<path to templates>/*tmpl'
```

We are getting emails but content is not right.

What we are getting in mail:

`<b> data is label_value </b>`

What we want:

**data is label_value**

So what we want is html output.

Can someone help with this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly I'd recommend against doing HTML on the Prometheus end, as that may cause maintenance issues as your system evolves.

It looks like Go's auto-escaping of HTML is what's happening here, so you need a way to tell Go's templating language that that's safe. The alertmanager doesn't have that function (Prometheus does), so I've filed https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/issues/314 for this.

Once that's fixed you'll be able to do `{{ .Annotations.header | safeHtml }}`

Comment: thanks @brian-brazil
Had tried safeHtml, got error like unknown function.

Comment: Make sure you're running from head. A release hasn't been made with that change yet.