# New Line character in email alerts

Tags: gmail, prometheus

How to print  new line character when sending emails? I'm sending it to gmail. The character `\n` prints literally. I even tried `</br>`  tag and yaml mutliline and none of them work.

```
 - alert: KubernetesPodImagePullBackOff
    expr: kube_pod_container_status_waiting_reason{reason=~"ContainerCreating|CrashLoopBackOff|ErrImagePull|ImagePullBackOff"} > 0
    for: 1s
    labels:
      severity: warning
    annotations:
      summary: "Kubernetes pod crash looping (instance {{ $labels.instance }}"
      description: "Pod {{ $labels.pod }} is crash looping\n VALUE = {{ $value }}\n LABELS: {{ $labels }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite default template in Alertmanager for E-mails.

You need to replace something like

```
{{ .Annotations.description }}
```

in template by

```
{{ .Annotations.description | safeHtml }}
```

I wrote for my own email template, if you have not your own, you may create it from
https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/blob/master/template/default.tmpl
and edit

```
{{ range .Annotations.SortedPairs }} - {{ .Name }} = {{ .Value }}
```

in the same manner with

```
{{ .Value  | safeHtml }}
```

Also read this answer
[prometheus using html content in alerts annotations and using it in email template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36735479/prometheus-using-html-content-in-alerts-annotations-and-using-it-in-email-templa)